# Convert a single column dataframe into an array/list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

My dataframe is as shown:

```
                     score
timestamp                      
1645401600.0      10.4
1645405200.0      22.4
1645408800.0      36.2
```

I want to convert it to an array of dictionaries.
Expected Result is :

```
result=[
    {
        timestamp:1645401600.0
        score:10.4
    },
    {
        timestamp:1645405200.0
        score:22.4
    },
    {
        timestamp:1645408800.0
        score:36.2
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you show us what code you have tried?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Here you go

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'score': [10.4, 22.4, 36.2]}, 
                  index = [1645401600.0, 1645405200.0, 1645408800.0])
df = df.rename_axis('timestamp').reset_index()
df = df.to_dict('records')
```

> Output

```
>>> [{'timestamp': 1645401600.0, 'score': 10.4}, 
     {'timestamp': 1645405200.0, 'score': 22.4}, 
     {'timestamp': 1645408800.0, 'score': 36.2}]
```

Comment: Please provide more commentary than "Here you go." Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service.

Comment: Please relax more, bro. Stack Overflow is not a chat room to make controversy, but to help people.

Comment: Correct, it is not a chat room. It is also a place to provide high-quality answers. As a new answerer, it might be helpful for you to read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). "Here you go" does not answer the question in any meaningful way.

Comment: Here you go bro: [Take it easy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RVmG_d3HKBA)

Answer (score 0):

Reset the index and then use `to_dict`:

```
result = df.reset_index().to_dict('records')
```

Output:

```
>>> result
[{'timestamp': 1645401600.0, 'score': 10.4},
 {'timestamp': 1645405200.0, 'score': 22.4},
 {'timestamp': 1645408800.0, 'score': 36.2}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use to_dict with records(https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html)

```
df.to_dict('records')
```

Comment: This doesn't work.

Comment: Can you show what you are doing?

Comment: It's supposed to be `records`, not `record`. Also, as `timestamp` is the index of the dataframe, you'll need to reset that first. But then, your answer will be a dupe of mine.

Comment: type edited. I have also added link if you want to understand this function.

Comment: This isn't my question. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
df.to_dict('records')
```

This is what you are looking for 
Important: parameter is 'records' and not 'record'